# Slicing in python

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a list of strings in python using the following code. I am unable to figure out what exactly the slicing in the following code

```
def sorted_order(colors):
    if not colors:
       return[] 
    return (sorted_order([x for x in colors[1:] if x <  colors[0]])
        + [colors[0]] +
        sorted_order([x for x in colors[1:] if x >= colors[0]]))
```

Comment: So, what is your question? You get unexpected output? If so, what output are you expecting vs. what are you getting?

Comment: Give us your input and expected output.

Comment: Assuming this is not an exercise in implementing a sorting algorithm, would `sorted(colors)` suffice?

Comment: It suppose to slice the list for next  `recursion` call so it will be with less items until the sorting is done, you need to provide more data in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is an ad-hoc quicksort implementation.

- `colors[0]` is the first value of the `colors` list and is used as the pivot for the quicksort.
- `colors[1:]` is a list containing all but the first value of `colors`.

(There's no good reason for this code to exist, in any case. You should use Python's built-in sort functions.)